# Python Bisection Search

Tags: python, python-3.x, bisection

I'm new to Python, currently doing the MIT edX course. We had a problem to complete where we had to use the bisection method to find the lowest payment a person had to make to pay off a credit card dept in a year.We were given the balance and the annual interest rate. My code below works but it does not look correct to me. Does anyone have any insight in this? Thanks

```
def payment(balance, annualInterestRate):
    newBalance = 0
    monthlyInterest = annualInterestRate / 12
    maxPaybal = (balance * (1 + monthlyInterest) ** 12) / 12
    minPaybal = balance/12
    while round(newBalance, 2) != 0.01 or round(newBalance, 2) != 0.00:
            guess = (minPaybal + maxPaybal) / 2.0
            newBalance = balance
            months = 12
            while months > 0:
                prevBalance = newBalance - guess
                uptdBalance = prevBalance + (prevBalance * monthlyInterest)
                newBalance = uptdBalance
                months -= 1
            if round(newBalance, 2) == 0.01 or round(newBalance, 2) == 0.00:
                return "Lowest Payment: ", round(guess, 2)
            elif newBalance < 0.00:
                maxPaybal = guess
            else:
                minPaybal = guess
print(payment(balance, annualInterestRate))
```

Comment: for starters, `monthlyInterest = annualInterestRate / 12` is not right. the interests compound during the year, so the value is `((1 + annualInterestRate) ** (1.0/12.0)) - 1`. You should be able to see that with the inconsistency in the value of your `maxBalance`, which should be 32000, but which is currently 32517

Comment: then, how do you know that your code works?

Comment: finally, where you explicitly asked to use bisection search for this?

Comment: @njzk2 the formula for the interest was what they gave us to use. I tested the code in my IDE and it also worked in their grader. Bisection search was the method they suggested we use, guess and check method would have taken too long to run in their grader with the ridiculous balances that were given. We could have used recursive functions as well but i'm yet to wrap my head around that.

Comment: `while round(newBalance, 2) != 0.01 or round(newBalance, 2) != 0.00:` this does nothing. it always evaluate to True, as newBalance cannot be equal to both values

Comment: ok i get what you're saying i can change that to while True, however newBalance can be either 0.01 or 0.00 since its an approximation.